# Hibernate : @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate

I have understood @joincolumn in hibernate. Now I have started with @JoinTable. Following is my POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private long person_id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String Address;


    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
        @JoinTable(name="person_phone",  
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="person_id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="phone_id", referencedColumnName="phone_id")})  
    private Phone phone;

        //Getters ande Setters

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "phone_id")
    private long phone_id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


        //Getters ande Setters


}
```

In my controller, I have done the following

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<person> listPersons() {     

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT * FROM person);  
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString()).addEntity(Person.class);
        return query.list();
    }
```

and when I execute as Select * from person . I am getting the following error

> ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The column name phone_id was
>   not found in this ResultSet.

What I want to achieve is , when I retrieve a record from **person** table I  want the corresponding **phone** details also .

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: In Phone, why the column name is "phone_id" but the variable name is person_id ?

Comment: Sorry , typo mistake. now corrected

Comment: Please add code to make us know how you build query. For example; calling CreateQuery method lines.

Comment: I have added the code of how I am retrieving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing Hibernate createQuery method instead createSqlQuery to match entity is more accurate.
Try below;

```
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("FROM Person");  //using hibernate query
    Query query = getSession().createQuery(sql.toString()); //Hibernate query so use createQuery not createSqlQuery
    return query.list();
```

Comment: `getSession().createQuery("FROM Person");` is pretty enough

Answer (score -1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long personId;  
    private String name;    
    private String address;
    private Phone phone;    

    public Person () {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "person_id") 
    public BigDecimal getPersonId() {
        return this.personId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")  
    public BigDecimal getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Column(name = "Address")
    public BigDecimal getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
        @JoinTable(name="person_phone",  
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="person_id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="phone_id", referencedColumnName="phone_id")})  
    public Phone getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }
    // setter function
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_phone")
public class Phone{

    private long personId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    public long getPersonId() {
        return this.personId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    //setter function
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve join table . person_id was a typo error and I changed it.

Comment: I updated the entities class, please give it a try, and help to correct typo if any :)

Comment: @VinhNT There are 3 tables on database, Person, person_phone and phone and 2 entities Person and Phone. Your solution is for joinColumn not for joinTable

Comment: I think that is the one-one relationship

Comment: I don't think this is even remotely right. The Phone entity should map to the phone table, not the person_phone table.